# How to disable on-screen keyboard when using touchscreen

Tags: gnome, keyboard, touchscreen

An on-screen keyboard is showing up every time I touch a text field when I use an external monitor with touchscreen. I don't want/need this feature since I have a physical keyboard.

Here's a picture of the virtual keyboard:

[image: The VKB showing up]

I read a lot about this issue, but didn't find any solution. I tried the gnome-extension "Block Caribou" but it's not working. Also, the extension was only tested on gnome 3.26 according to gnome-extensions website, so not sure if it's working properly on my system.

[image: Block-Caribou enabled]

Also, the on-screen keyboard is disabled in the accessibility settings (on the desktop and on the log-in screen). I think this keyboard must be located somewhere in my system and it should be possible to disable it if I would know where to look at.

System:
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with Gnome 3.36.8

Any help or ideas are very welcome.

EDIT:
I'll summarize here the comments below. `onboard`, `caribou` and `florence` are not installed in my system as shown by the `dpkg -L` command. I did not install any virtual keyboard manually (for example as gnome-extension). Only for this purpose and as a workaround I tried installing `caribou` and enabling again the BlockCaribou extension in the hope that it would block the new installed keyboard. It didn't work. I removed completely caribou. Any other ideas?

Comment: There are a number of virtual screen keyboards in Ubuntu such as `onboard`, `caribou` `florence` and `gnome shell's own VKB`. Does it look like this https://www.how2shout.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Start-using-the-On-screen-keyboard-of-Ubuntu-Linux.jpg

Comment: It's `gnome-shell-extension-onboard`. You can see it's content with `dpkg -L gnome-shell-extension-onboard`

Comment: This is a good point thanks for your help. The problem now is that `gnome-shell-extension-onboard` doesn't seem to be installed in my system. The command you gave says "not installed". Also `dpkg -l | grep "gnome-shell-extension"` returns `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`, `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`, `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`, `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`, `gnome-shell-extensions`. So where does it hide? I looked in `gnome-shell-extensions` but couldn't find anything that made me think of a keyboard...

Comment: Did you install any virtual keyboard from `gnome-extensions` such as https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3330/improved-onscreen-keyboard/

Comment: According to the description for `gnome-shell-extension-onboard` it's not the keyboard, just a button that lets you control it.  Installing that might let you pop it down.  The real keyboard is `onboard`

Comment: @kenn no `ls ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` returns `cariboublocker@git.keringar.xyz`

Comment: @user10489 I don't have any package called `onboard` on my computer. So apparently the On-Screen Keyboard is not an "extension" of any kind but probably a "default" feature...?

Comment: what is the output of `dpkg -L caribou`?

Comment: `pkg-query: package 'caribou' is not installed`  Same with florence and onboard. What about "gnome-shell's own VKB"? Where is this located?

Comment: If you are on X window system you can run `xprop` in terminal and click on thay keyboard to detect its name.

Comment: In the following link, it says that `just installing it is not enough. You need to enable it. The fastest way to do that is hit the super key and start typing "extensions". The extensions settings app should appear.` 
 https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/hkbtpk/i_cannot_disable_the_screenkeyboard_on_my/

Comment: Thanks for your answers. So ```xprop``` returns ```XdndProxy(WINDOW): window id # 0x400011```. I googled it a bit and Xdnd is the Drag-And-drop protocol for X. So the vkb is drawn in the "main" window. I couldn't find much more infos. For your other comment: I'll edit my post with a screenshot of block-caribou enabled, but it was already the case... Although block-caribou was only tested on 3.26 (according to gnome extensions website) so I don't even know if it's properly working on my system.

Comment: Try this https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3222/block-caribou-36/

Comment: It's working! Damn I didn't know this exists... If you put this as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you very very much!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with Gnome 3.36.8 `block caribou` extension by [@keringar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/) won't work. Instead of it use recent version of it by
[@lxylxy123456](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3222/block-caribou-36/)

Comment: Thank you, the next extension works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar situation in the past but it wasn't when using an external screen so maybe not be linked to your issue.

My problem was caused by having the accessibility on-screen keyboard enabled on the initial login screen. This setting is separate from the one in the settings found when logged in.

Log out of your user profile and at the top right of the screen you'll see a stick-man figure in a white circle. Click on that and you'll get a drop down menu and ensure the on-screen keyboard is off. Then log back into your user profile and try your touchscreen click in a text box again.

This fixed my issue but like I say this may not be the same thing for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I didn't know that these are two different settings. Unfortunately it didn't fix my problem since it was already disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Frustrating. Installed gnome-extension 'Improved OSK' and enabled option 'ignore touch-input'. Extension didn't disable 'touch-input' but it did take care of the onscreen keyboard!

Thank you NickShmyrev!
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4413/improved-osk/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is an accessibility setting.

**Settings** >> **Accessibility** >> **Typing** >> **Screen Keyboard**

Comment: Did you see the part that says "Also, the on-screen keyboard is disabled in the accessibility settings"?